# Trouble with my strategy buying but not selling in pine editor

Tags: trading, pine-script

I am using pine editor to make a strategy that buys when the D line which is the green line crosses under 17.5 and then sells when the D line crosses over 78. As you can see from the chart I have posted it should buy and sell a couple times but only buys once and does nothing else. I cant seem to figure out what I am missing. The bottom of the code is where I am telling it to by and sell in the strategy. Thanks

```
strategy("stochastic")
length = input(21, minval=1, title="length")  
rsilength = input(21, minval=1, title="rsi length")  
smoothk = input(4, minval=1, title="smoothk")
smoothd = input(10, minval=1, title="smoothd")
rsi = rsi(close, rsilength)

sto = stoch(close,highest(length),lowest(length), length)
K = sma(sto,smoothk)
D = sma(K,smoothd)

//plot(rsi, title="rsi", color=color.black)
plot(D, title="%D",color=color.green)
plot(K, title="%K",color=color.red)

hline(78,title="upper limit", color=color.red)
hline(17, title="lower limit",color=color.blue)
//plot(sto, title = "sto",color=color.black)


// === INPUT BACKTEST RANGE ===
FromMonth = input(defval = 8, title = "From Month", minval = 1, maxval = 12)
FromDay   = input(defval = 5, title = "From Day", minval = 1, maxval = 31)
FromYear  = input(defval = 2019, title = "From Year", minval = 2017)
ToMonth   = input(defval = 9, title = "To Month", minval = 1, maxval = 12)
ToDay     = input(defval = 1, title = "To Day", minval = 1, maxval = 31)
ToYear    = input(defval = 9999, title = "To Year", minval = 2017)

// === FUNCTION EXAMPLE ===
start     = timestamp(FromYear, FromMonth, FromDay, 00, 00)  // backtest start window
finish    = timestamp(ToYear, ToMonth, ToDay, 23, 59)        // backtest finish window
window()  => time >= start and time <= finish ? true : false // create function "within window of time"

// === EXECUTION ===
shares = 10000/close
buy = crossunder(D,17.5)
sell = crossover(D,78)

strategy.entry("buy", shares, when = window() and buy)  // buy long when "within window of time" AND crossover
strategy.close("sell", when = window() and sell)                // sell long when "within window of time" AND crossunder
```

This should buy and sell a couple times as seen highlighted in the picture.
https://ibb.co/37L0wSK  That is the link, sorry I do not have enough rep to post images.

Answer (score 1):

Your `strategy.close()` call wasn't using the same order id than the `strategy.entry()` call. I added markers in last 3 lines (you can turn them off via inputs) to show where your conditions are met.

> Note: make sure you include the first line in the script when you
>   transport Pine scripts. It's the compiler directive that specifies
>   which version of Pine the code is using, so it's important.

```
//@version=4
strategy("stochastic")
length = input(21, minval=1, title="length")  
rsilength = input(21, minval=1, title="rsi length")  
smoothk = input(4, minval=1, title="smoothk")
smoothd = input(10, minval=1, title="smoothd")
showMarkers = input(true, "Show Markers")

rsi = rsi(close, rsilength)

sto = stoch(close,highest(length),lowest(length), length)
K = sma(sto,smoothk)
D = sma(K,smoothd)

//plot(rsi, title="rsi", color=color.black)
plot(D, title="%D",color=color.green)
plot(K, title="%K",color=color.red)

hline(78,title="upper limit", color=color.red)
hline(17, title="lower limit",color=color.blue)
//plot(sto, title = "sto",color=color.black)


// === INPUT BACKTEST RANGE ===
FromMonth = input(defval = 8, title = "From Month", minval = 1, maxval = 12)
FromDay   = input(defval = 5, title = "From Day", minval = 1, maxval = 31)
FromYear  = input(defval = 2019, title = "From Year", minval = 2017)
ToMonth   = input(defval = 9, title = "To Month", minval = 1, maxval = 12)
ToDay     = input(defval = 1, title = "To Day", minval = 1, maxval = 31)
ToYear    = input(defval = 9999, title = "To Year", minval = 2017)

// === FUNCTION EXAMPLE ===
start     = timestamp(FromYear, FromMonth, FromDay, 00, 00)  // backtest start window
finish    = timestamp(ToYear, ToMonth, ToDay, 23, 59)        // backtest finish window
window()  => time >= start and time <= finish ? true : false // create function "within window of time"

// === EXECUTION ===
shares = 10000/close
buy = crossunder(D,17.5)
sell = crossover(D,78)

strategy.entry("buy", shares, when = window() and buy)  // buy long when "within window of time" AND crossover
strategy.close("buy", when = window() and sell)         // sell long when "within window of time" AND crossunder

plotshape(showMarkers and buy, "buy", shape.triangleup, location.bottom, color.green, 0, text = "buy", size = size.tiny)
plotshape(showMarkers and sell, "sell", shape.triangledown, location.top, color.maroon, 0, text = "sell", size = size.tiny)
bgcolor(showMarkers ? window() ? color.green : color.maroon : na)
```

[image]